# PostGIS ST within does not exist

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-query

I'm quite new to postgresql and postgis so this error will probably due to some rookie mistake.

I want to run the spatial query ST_within. When I describe the query like this

`SELECT nw.entity_id AS NavElem_id, nw.featuretype, nw.processingstatus AS NavElem_ProcessingStatus, nw.frc, nw.geometry AS NavElem_geom, aaa.processingstatus AS AA_processingstatus, aaa.networktype, aaa.geometry AS AA_geom, aaa.entity_id AS AA_id
FROM sml.network nw, sml.aa_geo_att aaa
WHERE ST_Within (nw.geometry, aaa.geometry);`

It works fine, however I do not want to provide the schema name everytime (in this case sml.), I want to make it generic so that I can use it in an sql file.

When I try to set the schema path in a first query and the ST_within in second query

```
SET search_path TO sml;
SELECT nw.entity_id AS NavElem_id, nw.featuretype, nw.processingstatus AS NavElem_ProcessingStatus, nw.frc, nw.geometry AS NavElem_geom, aaa.processingstatus AS AA_processingstatus, aaa.networktype, aaa.geometry AS AA_geom, aaa.entity_id AS AA_id
FROM network nw, aa_geo_att aaa
WHERE ST_Within (nw.geometry, aaa.geometry);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  function st_within(public.geometry, public.geometry) does not exist
LINE 5: WHERE ST_Within (nw.geometry, aaa.geometry);
          ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add   explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function st_within(public.geometry, public.geometry) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 311
```

Even though I set the schema, ST within is looking in the public schema, which I don't want.

Comment: Piggybacking on a comment by LR1234567 on a previous answer, the proper syntax for the ALTER DATABASE command as of PostgreSQL 9.x is: ALTER DATABASE my_database_name SET search_path = "$user", public, schema1, schema2; See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-alterdatabase.html (I would have simply commented after his comment, but I don't have enough reputation.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is that you have excluded the public schema from the search_path. All functions and types is in the public schema (by default)

So what you have to do is just include the public schema in the search_path

```
SET search_path TO sml, public;
```

means that the database will write to sml if you don't give any schema

```
SET search_path TO public, sml;
```

means that the database will write to public if no schema is given.

But in both cases both schemas will be searched for tables, functions and so on

Comment: So everytime I change the search_path to a schema, I also need to include the ,public?

It works now, thank you

Comment: @freakyfreak Yes.  In fact, that mirrors the default search path used by PostgreSQL: `$user, public`.

Comment: @Freakyfreak: If you are not happy with the database search path, you can change it with:  ALTER DATABASE SET search_path TO "$user", public, schema1, schema2, ...;   Then PostgreSQL will search the paths in that order.  You could also prefix the public schema on the function with something like public.ST_Within (though I personally don't do that).

Answer (score 1):

CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal;